difference between claiming a software invention as a method, apparatus, or system?
I see many software patents that essentially have multiple repeated claims claiming the same thing but in the form of a method, then system, and then apparatus.

What the difference between claiming a software as a method vs apparatus vs system?
Is there a reason not to claim all just to be safe?



What the difference between claiming a software as a method vs apparatus vs system?

The main difference is the type of activity that is considered to infringe each form of claim, when performed without authorization from the patent holder and without a few other exceptions, such as the exhaustion doctrine.
For example an apparatus need not be put into operation to directly infringe, while a method claim is usually directly infringed when put into operation.
Your first question is essentially too broad for a full answer (it would make a book).

Is there a reason not to claim all just to be safe?

Not really. Note that one can only claim what one genuinely believes one has invented. That being said, it would be rare that one has invented a computer-based apparatus that isn't inventive when viewed as a computer-implemented method also, etc.
Also, one gets 3 independent claims per application included in the basic filing fee. It is common to use these for process, apparatus, and system claims that have very similar recitations at their core.

If you can only claim 1, would the method claim be the broadest in protection?
